# listView.setBackgroundDrawable();

Tags: android, listview

My `listview` background doesn't change when calling `listView.setBackgroundDrawable()`.

I've searched a lot but didn't find a solution.

This is the code

```
ListView v= new ListView(Menu2.this);
v.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.android));
Context c=v.getContext();
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(c, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list));
```

The background stays as if I didn't call the method.

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried with my solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this :

```
ListView v= getListView();
v.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.android));
```

Instead of,

```
ListView v= new ListView(Menu2.this);
v.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.android));
```

Comment: it worked as magic but can u please explain why the old way did'nt work
Thanks

Comment: @MohamedShaban when you do this `ListView v= new ListView(Menu2.this);` it will make separate instance for the `ListView` and that's why it was not working. While `getListView()` returning current instance to use.